# Unable to fetch data in context menu from an API in tinymce5

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to fetch a list of items and show it on a context menu on right clicking any text on the editor.
I have implemented my ajax call on capturing the "onContextMenu" event, but that is fired after the menu is shown on the screen,
example--

```
   editor.on('contextmenu',function(e) {
      Utils.getList(e.target.innerHTML);
      });
```

By the time my call is complete , I already get an empty context menu. It shows the list on right clicking it on the 2nd time.

Please help resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE 5 context menu is synchronous only. We considered making it asynchronous but we only had one use case (spelling) and decided it over-complicated the API.

Please log a [github ticket](http://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues) so we can track this as a feature request :)

Comment: Hi @Sypder ... Already logged a ticket in Github .
Link - https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/5060

Comment: Oh! sorry I was a bit behind on my email. Yes, I'll log that on our internal tracker tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. try and look into it soon :)